ограничение выделения памяти под динамический массив
почему под динамический массив память выделяется максимум 8, хотя размер ввел 6
когда создаю динамический массив, выделяю под него память, то sizeof говорит, что выделено всего лишь столько байт, хотя под обычный массив все правильно выдает


Код должен быть текстом, а не скрином. Если кто то захочет воспроизвести вашу проблему, он врят ли будет это перепечатывать

Потому что, то что вы именуете динамическим массивом по факту (с т.з. компилятора) является указателем (его размер в 64-bit system как раз 8 байт). И еще, sizeof имеет дело всегда с объектами, размер которых известен во время компиляции. А создаваемая вами структура данных в памяти (тот самый динамический массив) появляется во время исполнения, поэтому sizeof к ней принципиально не применим

Это не выделенная память, функция sizeof() возвращает размер в байтах для конкретного типа переменной.
